# the dir parameter for calling roles

Tags: ansible

I've got this bit in my playbook.

```
 roles:
  - {role: cleanup-create, dir: '/standard/', commit: "{{choice}}"}
```

The file structure is /roles/standard/cleanup-create/tasks/main.yml

And yet I receive this error:

```
ERROR! the role 'cleanup-create' was not found in /home/myuser/network-ansible-myuser/roles:/home/myuser/network-ansible-myuser:/etc/ansible/roles

The error appears to have been in '/home/myuser/network-ansible-myuser/configure-files.yml': line 15, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
  - {role: cleanup-create, dir: '/standard', commit: "{{choice}}"}
    ^ here
```

Now, the error message seems to be saying my role wasn't found in /roles. However the dir parameter should make it look under /roles/standard.

It was working 5 minutes ago, I swear!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `dir` special parameter for roles.
It is just an ordinary variable, same as `commit` in your example.

You should place all your roles directly in `./roles` folder without any nesting.

Comment: I could have sworn I made it work. Maybe I looked at the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually set `roles_path` [configuration variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path) in `ansible.cfg` (or maybe [pass it in the command line](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) - try it, I'm not sure if you can do this with `roles_path`).

From the doc:

> The roles path indicate additional directories beyond the `roles/` subdirectory of a playbook project to search to find Ansible roles

./roles from playbook directory will be searched first, then additional paths will be checked.

You can specify multiple directories to look for roles in

```
roles_path=/var/opt/my_roles:/var/opt/more_roles
```